# How to use $context in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

After reading the Knockout documentation on [Binding Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), I would expect

this HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: blah">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($context, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    blah: {
        hello: "hello",
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

would print this:

```
blah: {
    hello: "hello",
}
```

However, I get the following error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: Error: Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed; Bindings value: text: ko.toJSON($context, null, 2)

How should it be used?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdavis/fmWMq/1/) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. $context and $parentContext just hold the special properties for that context. So in order to get what I was expecting I had to change the HTML to:

```
<div data-bind="with: blah">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($context.$data, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdavis/fmWMq/2/)

Comment: You don't really need you use the `$context` object there, just use `$data`.

Comment: Definitely true. I was mostly trying to understand how they worked, so I simplified it as much as possible.